# Exception when updating my wiki page title to be equal to its Name using workflow

Tags: 2013, workflow, development, sharepoint-server, enterprise-wiki

I am facing this problem inside my SharePoint server 2013 enterprise. I got the following:-
1. a site collection of type enterprise wiki.
2. since each wiki page have Name & title fields that are being updated separately. so i  created the following list workflow 2010 inside SharePoint designer 2013 , which will set the `title =Name` if they are not the same:-

[image]

but after deploying the workflow, whenever any user chnage the wiki page name they will receive the following exception:-

[image]

here is the related logs:-

```
06/30/2015 00:49:45.31  w3wp.exe (0x2AC0)                           0x0AAC  SharePoint Foundation           Legacy Workflow Infrastructure  72er    Medium      Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: The file Pages/test page New.aspx has been modified by i:0#.w|tdmgroup\sptest on 30 Jun 2015 00:49:45 +0100. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: <nativehr>0x81020015</nativehr><nativestack>owssvr.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=0000000000015B8F) at 0x000007FEE4D45B8F Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.ni.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=00000000000A75AB) at 0x000007FEE83875AB </nativestack>The file Pages/test page New.aspx has been modified by i:0#.w|tdmgroup\sptest on 30 Jun 2015 00:49:45 +0100.     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.AddOrUpdateItem(String bstrUrl, String bstrListName, Boolean bAdd, Boolean bSystemUpdate, Boolean bPreserveItemVersion, Boolean bPreserveItemUIVersion, Boolean bUpdateNoVersion, Int32&... 6d3e159d-e84a-f084-3eee-f32696758447
06/30/2015 00:49:45.31* w3wp.exe (0x2AC0)                           0x0AAC  SharePoint Foundation           Legacy Workflow Infrastructure  72er    Medium      ... plID, String& pbstrGuid, Guid pbstrNewDocId, Boolean bHasNewDocId, String bstrVersion, Object& pvarAttachmentNames, Object& pvarAttachmentContents, Object& pvarProperties, Boolean bCheckOut, Boolean bCheckin, Boolean bUnRestrictedUpdateInProgress, Boolean bMigration, Boolean bPublish, String bstrFileName, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pListDataValidationCallback, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pRestrictInsertCallback, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pUniqueFieldCallback)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.AddOrUpdateItem(String bstrUrl, String bstrListName, Boolean bAdd, Boolean bSystemUpdate, Boolean bPreserveItemVersion, Boolean bPreserveItemUIVersion, Boolean bUpdateNoVersion, Int32& plID, String& pbstrGuid, Guid pbstrNewDocId, Boolean bHasNewDocId, String bstrVersion, Object& pvarAttachmentNames, Object...  6d3e159d-e84a-f084-3eee-f32696758447
06/30/2015 00:49:45.31* w3wp.exe (0x2AC0)                           0x0AAC  SharePoint Foundation           Legacy Workflow Infrastructure  72er    Medium      ...& pvarAttachmentContents, Object& pvarProperties, Boolean bCheckOut, Boolean bCheckin, Boolean bUnRestrictedUpdateInProgress, Boolean bMigration, Boolean bPublish, String bstrFileName, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pListDataValidationCallback, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pRestrictInsertCallback, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pUniqueFieldCallback)     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleComException(COMException comEx)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.AddOrUpdateItem(String bstrUrl, String bstrListName, Boolean bAdd, Boolean bSystemUpdate, Boolean bPreserveItemVersion, Boolean bPreserveItemUIVersion, Boolean bUpdateNoVersion, Int32& plID, String& pbstrGuid, Guid pbstrNewDocId, Boolean bHasNewDocId, String bstrVersion, Object& pvarAttachmentNames, Object...  6d3e159d-e84a-f084-3eee-f32696758447
06/30/2015 00:49:45.31* w3wp.exe (0x2AC0)                           0x0AAC  SharePoint Foundation           Legacy Workflow Infrastructure  72er    Medium      ...& pvarAttachmentContents, Object& pvarProperties, Boolean bCheckOut, Boolean bCheckin, Boolean bUnRestrictedUpdateInProgress, Boolean bMigration, Boolean bPublish, String bstrFileName, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pListDataValidationCallback, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pRestrictInsertCallback, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pUniqueFieldCallback)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.AddOrUpdateItem(Boolean bAdd, Boolean bSystem, Boolean bPreserveItemVersion, Boolean bNoVersion, Boolean bMigration, Boolean bPublish, Boolean bCheckOut, Boolean bCheckin, Guid newGuidOnAdd, Int32& ulID, Object& objAttachmentNames, Object& objAttachmentContents, Boolean suppressAfterEvents, String filename, Boolean bPreserveItemUIVersion)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.UpdateInternal(Boolean bSystem, Boolean bPreserveItemVers...  6d3e159d-e84a-f084-3eee-f32696758447
06/30/2015 00:49:45.31* w3wp.exe (0x2AC0)                           0x0AAC  SharePoint Foundation           Legacy Workflow Infrastructure  72er    Medium      ...ion, Guid newGuidOnAdd, Boolean bMigration, Boolean bPublish, Boolean bNoVersion, Boolean bCheckOut, Boolean bCheckin, Boolean suppressAfterEvents, String filename, Boolean bPreserveItemUIVersion)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.Update()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPWinOEWSSService.CommitUpdateDocument(Transaction txn, Object[] transData)    6d3e159d-e84a-f084-3eee-f32696758447
06/30/2015 00:49:45.32  w3wp.exe (0x2AC0)                           0x0AAC  SharePoint Foundation           Legacy Workflow Infrastructure  72fe    High        Error in commiting pending workflow batch items: Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: The file Pages/test page New.aspx has been modified by i:0#.w|tdmgroup\sptest on 30 Jun 2015 00:49:45 +0100. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: <nativehr>0x81020015</nativehr><nativestack>owssvr.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=0000000000015B8F) at 0x000007FEE4D45B8F Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.ni.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=00000000000A75AB) at 0x000007FEE83875AB </nativestack>The file Pages/test page New.aspx has been modified by i:0#.w|tdmgroup\sptest on 30 Jun 2015 00:49:45 +0100.     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.AddOrUpdateItem(String bstrUrl, String bstrListName, Boolean bAdd, Boolean bSystemUpdate, Boolean bPreserveItemVersion, Boolean bPreser... 6d3e159d-e84a-f084-3eee-f32696758447
06/30/2015 00:49:45.32* w3wp.exe (0x2AC0)                           0x0AAC  SharePoint Foundation           Legacy Workflow Infrastructure  72fe    High        ...veItemUIVersion, Boolean bUpdateNoVersion, Int32& plID, String& pbstrGuid, Guid pbstrNewDocId, Boolean bHasNewDocId, String bstrVersion, Object& pvarAttachmentNames, Object& pvarAttachmentContents, Object& pvarProperties, Boolean bCheckOut, Boolean bCheckin, Boolean bUnRestrictedUpdateInProgress, Boolean bMigration, Boolean bPublish, String bstrFileName, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pListDataValidationCallback, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pRestrictInsertCallback, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pUniqueFieldCallback)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.AddOrUpdateItem(String bstrUrl, String bstrListName, Boolean bAdd, Boolean bSystemUpdate, Boolean bPreserveItemVersion, Boolean bPreserveItemUIVersion, Boolean bUpdateNoVersion, Int32& plID, String& pbstrGuid, Guid pbstrNewDocId, Boolean bHasNewDocId, String...  6d3e159d-e84a-f084-3eee-f32696758447
06/30/2015 00:49:45.32* w3wp.exe (0x2AC0)                           0x0AAC  SharePoint Foundation           Legacy Workflow Infrastructure  72fe    High        ... bstrVersion, Object& pvarAttachmentNames, Object& pvarAttachmentContents, Object& pvarProperties, Boolean bCheckOut, Boolean bCheckin, Boolean bUnRestrictedUpdateInProgress, Boolean bMigration, Boolean bPublish, String bstrFileName, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pListDataValidationCallback, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pRestrictInsertCallback, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pUniqueFieldCallback)     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleComException(COMException comEx)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.AddOrUpdateItem(String bstrUrl, String bstrListName, Boolean bAdd, Boolean bSystemUpdate, Boolean bPreserveItemVersion, Boolean bPreserveItemUIVersion, Boolean bUpdateNoVersion, Int32& plID, String& pbstrGuid, Guid pbstrNewDocId, Boolean bHasNewDocId, String...  6d3e159d-e84a-f084-3eee-f32696758447
06/30/2015 00:49:45.32* w3wp.exe (0x2AC0)                           0x0AAC  SharePoint Foundation           Legacy Workflow Infrastructure  72fe    High        ... bstrVersion, Object& pvarAttachmentNames, Object& pvarAttachmentContents, Object& pvarProperties, Boolean bCheckOut, Boolean bCheckin, Boolean bUnRestrictedUpdateInProgress, Boolean bMigration, Boolean bPublish, String bstrFileName, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pListDataValidationCallback, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pRestrictInsertCallback, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pUniqueFieldCallback)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.AddOrUpdateItem(Boolean bAdd, Boolean bSystem, Boolean bPreserveItemVersion, Boolean bNoVersion, Boolean bMigration, Boolean bPublish, Boolean bCheckOut, Boolean bCheckin, Guid newGuidOnAdd, Int32& ulID, Object& objAttachmentNames, Object& objAttachmentContents, Boolean suppressAfterEvents, String filename, Boolean bPreserveItemUIVersion)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.UpdateIn...  6d3e159d-e84a-f084-3eee-f32696758447
06/30/2015 00:49:45.32* w3wp.exe (0x2AC0)                           0x0AAC  SharePoint Foundation           Legacy Workflow Infrastructure  72fe    High        ...ternal(Boolean bSystem, Boolean bPreserveItemVersion, Guid newGuidOnAdd, Boolean bMigration, Boolean bPublish, Boolean bNoVersion, Boolean bCheckOut, Boolean bCheckin, Boolean suppressAfterEvents, String filename, Boolean bPreserveItemUIVersion)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.Update()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPWinOEWSSService.CommitUpdateDocument(Transaction txn, Object[] transData)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPPendingWorkBatch.Commit(Transaction transaction, ICollection items)    6d3e159d-e84a-f084-3eee-f32696758447
06/30/2015 00:49:45.32  NodeRunnerAnalytics1-4c3a4290-d (0x1514)    0x25D4  Search                          Logging Correlation Data        77a3    Verbose     Ending correlation. 0c950427-fe31-4b20-be58-ad5703145423
06/30/2015 00:49:45.34  SPUCWorkerProcessProxy.exe (0x0B34)         0x1564  SharePoint Foundation           General                         narq    Verbose     Releasing SPRequest with allocation Id {5CF9F1C6-D2CC-4EF4-9E43-4E7294002304}    
06/30/2015 00:49:45.35  NodeRunner.exe (0x1520)                     0x1BCC  SharePoint Foundation           General                         narq    Verbose     Releasing SPRequest with allocation Id {F527C4B5-D105-4075-81FF-3CBAD074A54E}    
06/30/2015 00:49:45.44  w3wp.exe (0x2AC0)                           0x0AAC  SharePoint Foundation           Legacy Workflow Infrastructure  ahk8s   Verbose     Calling SaveInstanceData for workflow instance: b08ca8d9-5e4a-40e8-be48-11b383b3f1cd, instance data size: 0, internal state: Locked, Running, NotStarted, processing id: c86adf53-e9b3-48db-aaba-2256bf04e833   6d3e159d-e84a-f084-3eee-f32696758447
06/30/2015 00:49:45.44  w3wp.exe (0x2AC0)                           0x0AAC  SharePoint Foundation           Database                        tzku    Verbose     ConnectionString: 'Data Source=SharePointDev;Initial Catalog=WSS_Content;Integrated Security=True;Enlist=False;Pooling=True;Min Pool Size=0;Max Pool Size=100;Connect Timeout=15'    Partition: 37692b93-c136-4691-8e4d-85b3273e32a8 ConnectionState: Closed ConnectionTimeout: 15  6d3e159d-e84a-f084-3eee-f32696758447
06/30/2015 00:49:45.44  w3wp.exe (0x2AC0)                           0x0AAC  SharePoint Foundation           Database                        ahjqp   Verbose     SQL connection time: 0.119079380200556 for Data Source=SharePointDev;Initial Catalog=WSS_Content;Integrated Security=True;Enlist=False;Pooling=True;Min Pool Size=0;Max Pool Size=100;Connect Timeout=15    6d3e159d-e84a-f084-3eee-f32696758447
06/30/2015 00:49:45.45  w3wp.exe (0x2AC0)                           0x0AAC  SharePoint Foundation           Legacy Workflow Infrastructure  ahk8u   Verbose     Successfully persisted workflow instance: b08ca8d9-5e4a-40e8-be48-11b383b3f1cd with error code: 0, instance data size: 0, internal state: Locked, Running, NotStarted, processing id: c86adf53-e9b3-48db-aaba-2256bf04e833  6d3e159d-e84a-f084-3eee-f32696758447
06/30/2015 00:49:45.46  w3wp.exe (0x2AC0)                           0x0AAC  SharePoint Foundation           Upgrade                         ajyiy   Verbose     06/30/2015 00:49:45.46 w3wp (0x2AC0) 0x0AAC SharePoint Foundation Upgrade SPManager ajyiy VERBOSE Using cached [SPContentDatabase Name=WSS_Content] NeedsUpgrade value: False. 6d3e159d-e84a-f084-3eee-f32696758447 6d3e159d-e84a-f084-3eee-f32696758447
06/30/2015 00:49:45.46  w3wp.exe (0x2AC0)                           0x0AAC  SharePoint Foundation           Upgrade                         ajyix   Verbose     06/30/2015 00:49:45.46 w3wp (0x2AC0) 0x0AAC SharePoint Foundation Upgrade SPManager ajyix VERBOSE Using cached [SPContentDatabase Name=WSS_Content] IsBackwardsCompatible value: True. 6d3e159d-e84a-f084-3eee-f32696758447 6d3e159d-e84a-f084-3eee-f32696758447
06/30/2015 00:49:45.46  w3wp.exe (0x2AC0)                           0x0AAC  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      nasq    Verbose     Entering monitored scope (SPSqlClient). Parent WorkflowTelemetryScope   6d3e159d-e84a-f084-3eee-f32696758447
06/30/2015 00:49:45.46  w3wp.exe (0x2AC0)                           0x0AAC  SharePoint Foundation           Database                        tkeb    Verbose     Setting database session for 28d90a54-924f-4a74-8e6d-9422a91541d8 and site 37692b93-c136-4691-8e4d-85b3273e32a8.    6d3e159d-e84a-f084-3eee-f32696758447
06/30/2015 00:49:45.46  w3wp.exe (0x2AC0)                           0x0AAC  SharePoint Foundation           Database                        tzku    Verbose     ConnectionString: 'Data Source=SharePointDev;Initial Catalog=WSS_Content;Integrated Security=True;Enlist=False;Pooling=True;Min Pool Size=0;Max Pool Size=100;Connect Timeout=15'    Partition: 37692b93-c136-4691-8e4d-85b3273e32a8 ConnectionState: Closed ConnectionTimeout: 15  6d3e159d-e84a-f084-3eee-f32696758447
06/30/2015 00:49:45.47  w3wp.exe (0x2AC0)                           0x0AAC  SharePoint Foundation           Database                        ahjqp   Verbose     SQL connection time: 0.270704796279974 for Data Source=SharePointDev;Initial Catalog=WSS_Content;Integrated Security=True;Enlist=False;Pooling=True;Min Pool Size=0;Max Pool Size=100;Connect Timeout=15    6d3e159d-e84a-f084-3eee-f32696758447
06/30/2015 00:49:45.47  w3wp.exe (0x2AC0)                           0x0AAC  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    Verbose     Leaving Monitored Scope (SPSqlClient). Execution Time=3.33610836014074  6d3e159d-e84a-f084-3eee-f32696758447
06/30/2015 00:49:45.47  w3wp.exe (0x2AC0)                           0x0AAC  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      nass    Verbose     ____CPU Cycles=4552124  6d3e159d-e84a-f084-3eee-f32696758447
06/30/2015 00:49:45.47  w3wp.exe (0x2AC0)                           0x0AAC  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      nass    Verbose     ____Execution Time=3.33610836014074 6d3e159d-e84a-f084-3eee-f32696758447
06/30/2015 00:49:45.47  w3wp.exe (0x2AC0)                           0x0AAC  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      nasq    Verbose     Entering monitored scope (SPSqlClient). Parent WorkflowTelemetryScope   6d3e159d-e84a-f084-3eee-f32696758447
06/30/2015 00:49:45.47  w3wp.exe (0x2AC0)                           0x0AAC  SharePoint Foundation           Database                        tkeb    Verbose     Setting database session for 28d90a54-924f-4a74-8e6d-9422a91541d8 and site 37692b93-c136-4691-8e4d-85b3273e32a8.    6d3e159d-e84a-f084-3eee-f32696758447
06/30/2015 00:49:45.47  w3wp.exe (0x2AC0)                           0x0AAC  SharePoint Foundation           Database                        tzku    Verbose     ConnectionString: 'Data Source=SharePointDev;Initial Catalog=WSS_Content;Integrated Security=True;Enlist=False;Pooling=True;Min Pool Size=0;Max Pool Size=100;Connect Timeout=15'    Partition: 37692b93-c136-4691-8e4d-85b3273e32a8 ConnectionState: Closed ConnectionTimeout: 15  6d3e159d-e84a-f084-3eee-f32696758447
06/30/2015 00:49:45.47  w3wp.exe (0x2AC0)                           0x0AAC  SharePoint Foundation           Database                        ahjqp   Verbose     SQL connection time: 0.0720063583500138 for Data Source=SharePointDev;Initial Catalog=WSS_Content;Integrated Security=True;Enlist=False;Pooling=True;Min Pool Size=0;Max Pool Size=100;Connect Timeout=15   6d3e159d-e84a-f084-3eee-f32696758447
06/30/2015 00:49:45.48  w3wp.exe (0x2AC0)                           0x0AAC  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    Verbose     Leaving Monitored Scope (SPSqlClient). Execution Time=14.5870494713714  6d3e159d-e84a-f084-3eee-f32696758447
06/30/2015 00:49:45.48  w3wp.exe (0x2AC0)                           0x0AAC  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      nass    Verbose     ____CPU Cycles=1932536  6d3e159d-e84a-f084-3eee-f32696758447
06/30/2015 00:49:45.48  w3wp.exe (0x2AC0)                           0x0AAC  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      nass    Verbose     ____Execution Time=14.5870494713714 6d3e159d-e84a-f084-3eee-f32696758447
06/30/2015 00:49:45.49  w3wp.exe (0x2AC0)                           0x0AAC  SharePoint Foundation           Legacy Workflow Infrastructure  88xr    Unexpected  WinWF Internal Error, terminating workflow Id# b08ca8d9-5e4a-40e8-be48-11b383b3f1cd 6d3e159d-e84a-f084-3eee-f32696758447
06/30/2015 00:49:45.49  w3wp.exe (0x2AC0)                           0x0AAC  SharePoint Foundation           Legacy Workflow Infrastructure  98d4    Unexpected  System.Workflow.Runtime.Hosting.PersistenceException: The file Pages/test page New.aspx has been modified by i:0#.w|tdmgroup\sptest on 30 Jun 2015 00:49:45 +0100. ---> Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: The file Pages/test page New.aspx has been modified by i:0#.w|tdmgroup\sptest on 30 Jun 2015 00:49:45 +0100. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: <nativehr>0x81020015</nativehr><nativestack>owssvr.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=0000000000015B8F) at 0x000007FEE4D45B8F Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.ni.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=00000000000A75AB) at 0x000007FEE83875AB </nativestack>The file Pages/test page New.aspx has been modified by i:0#.w|tdmgroup\sptest on 30 Jun 2015 00:49:45 +0100.     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.AddOrUpdateItem(... 6d3e159d-e84a-f084-3eee-f32696758447
06/30/2015 00:49:45.49* w3wp.exe (0x2AC0)                           0x0AAC  SharePoint Foundation           Legacy Workflow Infrastructure  98d4    Unexpected  ...String bstrUrl, String bstrListName, Boolean bAdd, Boolean bSystemUpdate, Boolean bPreserveItemVersion, Boolean bPreserveItemUIVersion, Boolean bUpdateNoVersion, Int32& plID, String& pbstrGuid, Guid pbstrNewDocId, Boolean bHasNewDocId, String bstrVersion, Object& pvarAttachmentNames, Object& pvarAttachmentContents, Object& pvarProperties, Boolean bCheckOut, Boolean bCheckin, Boolean bUnRestrictedUpdateInProgress, Boolean bMigration, Boolean bPublish, String bstrFileName, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pListDataValidationCallback, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pRestrictInsertCallback, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pUniqueFieldCallback)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.AddOrUpdateItem(String bstrUrl, String bstrListName, Boolean bAdd, Boolean bSystemUpdate, Boolean bPreserveItemVersion, Boolean bPreserveIt...  6d3e159d-e84a-f084-3eee-f32696758447
06/30/2015 00:49:45.49* w3wp.exe (0x2AC0)                           0x0AAC  SharePoint Foundation           Legacy Workflow Infrastructure  98d4    Unexpected  ...emUIVersion, Boolean bUpdateNoVersion, Int32& plID, String& pbstrGuid, Guid pbstrNewDocId, Boolean bHasNewDocId, String bstrVersion, Object& pvarAttachmentNames, Object& pvarAttachmentContents, Object& pvarProperties, Boolean bCheckOut, Boolean bCheckin, Boolean bUnRestrictedUpdateInProgress, Boolean bMigration, Boolean bPublish, String bstrFileName, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pListDataValidationCallback, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pRestrictInsertCallback, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pUniqueFieldCallback)     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleComException(COMException comEx)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.AddOrUpdateItem(String bstrUrl, String bstrListName, Boolean bAdd, Boolean bSystemUpdate, Boolean bPreserveItemVersion, Boolean bPreserveIt...  6d3e159d-e84a-f084-3eee-f32696758447
06/30/2015 00:49:45.49* w3wp.exe (0x2AC0)                           0x0AAC  SharePoint Foundation           Legacy Workflow Infrastructure  98d4    Unexpected  ...emUIVersion, Boolean bUpdateNoVersion, Int32& plID, String& pbstrGuid, Guid pbstrNewDocId, Boolean bHasNewDocId, String bstrVersion, Object& pvarAttachmentNames, Object& pvarAttachmentContents, Object& pvarProperties, Boolean bCheckOut, Boolean bCheckin, Boolean bUnRestrictedUpdateInProgress, Boolean bMigration, Boolean bPublish, String bstrFileName, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pListDataValidationCallback, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pRestrictInsertCallback, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pUniqueFieldCallback)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.AddOrUpdateItem(Boolean bAdd, Boolean bSystem, Boolean bPreserveItemVersion, Boolean bNoVersion, Boolean bMigration, Boolean bPublish, Boolean bCheckOut, Boolean bCheckin, Guid newGuidOnAdd, Int32& ulID, Object& objAttachmentNames, Object& objAttachmentContents, Boolea...  6d3e159d-e84a-f084-3eee-f32696758447
06/30/2015 00:49:45.49* w3wp.exe (0x2AC0)                           0x0AAC  SharePoint Foundation           Legacy Workflow Infrastructure  98d4    Unexpected  ...n suppressAfterEvents, String filename, Boolean bPreserveItemUIVersion)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.UpdateInternal(Boolean bSystem, Boolean bPreserveItemVersion, Guid newGuidOnAdd, Boolean bMigration, Boolean bPublish, Boolean bNoVersion, Boolean bCheckOut, Boolean bCheckin, Boolean suppressAfterEvents, String filename, Boolean bPreserveItemUIVersion)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.Update()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPWinOEWSSService.CommitUpdateDocument(Transaction txn, Object[] transData)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPPendingWorkBatch.Commit(Transaction transaction, ICollection items)     at System.Workflow.Runtime.WorkBatch.PendingWorkCollection.Commit(Transaction transaction)     at System.Workflow.Runtime.WorkBatch.Commit(Transaction transaction)...  6d3e159d-e84a-f084-3eee-f32696758447
06/30/2015 00:49:45.49* w3wp.exe (0x2AC0)                           0x0AAC  SharePoint Foundation           Legacy Workflow Infrastructure  98d4    Unexpected  ...     at System.Workflow.Runtime.Hosting.WorkflowCommitWorkBatchService.CommitWorkBatch(CommitWorkBatchCallback commitWorkBatchCallback)     at System.Workflow.Runtime.Hosting.DefaultWorkflowCommitWorkBatchService.CommitWorkBatch(CommitWorkBatchCallback commitWorkBatchCallback)     at System.Workflow.Runtime.WorkflowExecutor.CommitTransaction(Activity activityContext)     at System.Workflow.Runtime.WorkflowExecutor.Persist(Activity dynamicActivity, Boolean unlock, Boolean needsCompensation)     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---     at System.Workflow.Runtime.WorkflowExecutor.Persist(Activity dynamicActivity, Boolean unlock, Boolean needsCompensation)     at System.Workflow.Runtime.WorkflowExecutor.System.Workflow.ComponentModel.IWorkflowCoreRuntime.PersistInstanceState(Activity act...  6d3e159d-e84a-f084-3eee-f32696758447
06/30/2015 00:49:45.49* w3wp.exe (0x2AC0)                           0x0AAC  SharePoint Foundation           Legacy Workflow Infrastructure  98d4    Unexpected  ...ivity)     at System.Workflow.ComponentModel.Activity.MarkClosed()     at System.Workflow.ComponentModel.Activity.ReleaseLockOnStatusChange(IActivityEventListener`1 eventListener)     at System.Workflow.ComponentModel.FaultAndCancellationHandlingFilter.SafeReleaseLockOnStatusChange(ActivityExecutionContext context)     at System.Workflow.ComponentModel.FaultAndCancellationHandlingFilter.OnEvent(Object sender, ActivityExecutionStatusChangedEventArgs e)     at System.Workflow.ComponentModel.ActivityExecutorDelegateInfo`1.ActivityExecutorDelegateOperation.Run(IWorkflowCoreRuntime workflowCoreRuntime)     at System.Workflow.Runtime.Scheduler.Run()  6d3e159d-e84a-f084-3eee-f32696758447
```

i found many exceptions realted to legacy workflow infrascture, but not sure what is causing these exceptions. now the original page name is "`Test Page.aspx`" and i tried to rename it to "`TEst Page New.aspx`". so can anyone adivce how i can fix this problem ?

Comment: @Eric Alexander you marked this as a duplicate !!! they are 2 different questions ?? please read carefully

Comment: @Eric Alexander please remove this as duplicate because it is not a duplicate !!!

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies as you are updating Title with Name, the `.aspx` extension is also getting appended. Try updating the page name to something else and if it works then do a string manipulation in the workflow so that `.aspx` doesn't get included when you are copying the Name to Title.

Please share your results for the solution, maybe I can help you better if it doesn't work.

Comment: but i do not think this is the problem, because if after reeving the error i refresh the web page , the page title will get updated correctly, with the page name without the .aspx extension. in all ways the page name will not have .aspx extension... so i do not think this is the problem ...

Comment: Goal can you advice please ?

Comment: also i noted something. now if i manually type .aspx inside the page title it will not raise any problem. so i am sure there is something else causing this problem ...